# How to get total value when the user ask to repeat the program?

Tags: java, oop

I'm an absolute beginner and I'm writing a program for an online shop, I have 3 departments and I've started with the women's department. I ask the user if they want to add another product and if yes then what I'm trying to do is to repeat the program and add the values from each repetition and only print the total but my code isn't working the way I need it to work.

```
public class WomenDep extends Shop{
    int a,c,d,NoOfSizes=3,Counter;
    double b,Total;
    Prices P1 = new Prices();
    double []arr = new double[NoOfSizes];
    @Override
     public void GetDet(){
        System.out.println("Pls Select Product No., \n(1)--> Tshirt\n(2)--> Short\n(3)--> Jeans\n"
                + "(4)--> Dress\n(5)--> Skirts");
        a = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Pls Select required Size No., \n(1)-->S\n(2)-->M\n(3)-->L");
        b = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Number of Pieces");
        c = input.nextInt();
        this.Pieces=c;
         System.out.println("Do you want to add another product to your cart?\n(1)-->Yes\n(2)-->No");
        d = input.nextInt();
    }

    @Override
     public double [] SearchArr(){
         if(this.a==1){
            this.ProductName = "Tshirt";
            for (int i = 0; i<NoOfSizes; ++i)
                arr[i]=P1.WTshirt[i];
            }
         if(this.a==2){
            this.ProductName = "Short";
         for (int i = 0; i<NoOfSizes; ++i)
                arr[i]=P1.WShort[i];
            }
         if(this.a==3){
            this.ProductName = "Jeans";
         for (int i = 0; i<NoOfSizes; ++i)
                arr[i]=P1.WJeans[i];
            }
         if(this.a==4){
            this.ProductName = "Dress";
         for (int i = 0; i<NoOfSizes; ++i)
                arr[i]=P1.WDress[i];
            }
         if(this.a==5){
            this.ProductName = "Skirts";
         for (int i = 0; i<NoOfSizes; ++i)
                arr[i]=P1.WSkirts[i];
         }
          return arr;
     }

    @Override
     public double CalPrice(){
         if(b==1){
                Price = arr [0];}
         if(b==2){
                Price = arr [1];}
         else if(b==3){
                Price = arr [2];}
         return Price;
     }

    @Override
     public void TotalPrice(){
         TPrice =Price * Pieces;
         System.out.println("this is total Price "+TPrice);
     }

    @Override
     public void Recal(){ 
            do{
            this.GetDet();
            this.SearchArr();
            this.CalPrice();
            this.TotalPrice();
            }while(d==1);
        }
     }
public class Prices extends Shop{
    public double [] WTshirt = {60.00,100.5,120};//S,M,L
    public double [] WShort = {50,110,130.5};//S,M,L
    public double [] WJeans = {150.99,180,200};//S,M,L
    public double [] WDress = {350,400,450.99};//S,M,L
    public double [] WSkirts = {350.5,499.99,450.5};//S,M,L
}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     WomenDep a = new WomenDep();
     a.Recal();

    }
```

I expect it to add the total value of the calculated price each time but it only calculates one.

Comment: Please consider naming conventions. In java CamelCase is pretty convenient. There is UpperCamelCase for classes and lowerCamelCase for variables. Constants are usually written completely in UPPERCASE. [CamelCase Notation](https://sanaulla.info/2008/06/25/camelcase-notation-naming-convention-for-programming-languages/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you calculating the price is going to work just once only.

1. Change the call to this.CalPrice() to store the return from the function.
2. Create Price as your global variable, to store the updated price

   ```
   public void Recal(){ 
   do{
       this.GetDet();
       this.SearchArr();
       double Price = this.CalPrice();
       this.TotalPrice();
   }while(d==1);
   }
   ```
3. Change the TotalPrice function to update the price
4. Create TPrice variable globally, to get the latest updated price

   ```
   public void TotalPrice(){
    TPrice = TPrice + this.Price * Pieces;
   System.out.println("this is total Price "+TPrice);
   }
   ```

Complete code, I have removed the extend class part, Please have a look and check if the issue is been resolved.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WomenDep{
int a,c,d,NoOfSizes=3,Counter;
double b,Total;
Prices P1 = new Prices();
double []arr = new double[NoOfSizes];
private int Pieces;
double Price;
double TPrice;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private String ProductName;

public void GetDet(){
    System.out.println("Pls Select Product No., \n(1)--> Tshirt\n(2)--> Short\n(3)--> Jeans\n"
            + "(4)--> Dress\n(5)--> Skirts");
    a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Pls Select required Size No., \n(1)-->S\n(2)-->M\n(3)-->L");
    b = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Number of Pieces");
    c = input.nextInt();
    this.Pieces=c;
    System.out.println("Do you want to add another product to your cart?\n(1)-->Yes\n(2)-->No");
    d = input.nextInt();
}


public double [] SearchArr(){
    if(this.a==1){
        this.ProductName = "Tshirt";
        for (int i = 0; i<NoOfSizes; ++i)
            arr[i]=P1.WTshirt[i];
    }
    if(this.a==2){
        this.ProductName = "Short";
        for (int i = 0; i<NoOfSizes; ++i)
            arr[i]=P1.WShort[i];
    }
    if(this.a==3){
        this.ProductName = "Jeans";
        for (int i = 0; i<NoOfSizes; ++i)
            arr[i]=P1.WJeans[i];
    }
    if(this.a==4){
        this.ProductName = "Dress";
        for (int i = 0; i<NoOfSizes; ++i)
            arr[i]=P1.WDress[i];
    }
    if(this.a==5){
        this.ProductName = "Skirts";
        for (int i = 0; i<NoOfSizes; ++i)
            arr[i]=P1.WSkirts[i];
    }
    return arr;
}


public double CalPrice(){

    if(b==1){
        Price = arr [0];}
    if(b==2){
        Price = arr [1];}
    else if(b==3){
        Price = arr [2];}
    return Price;
}


public void TotalPrice(){
     TPrice = TPrice + this.Price * Pieces;
    System.out.println("this is total Price "+TPrice);
}


public void Recal(){ 
    do{
        this.GetDet();
        this.SearchArr();
        double Price = this.CalPrice();
        this.TotalPrice();
    }while(d==1);
}
 class Prices{
    public double [] WTshirt = {60.00,100.5,120};//S,M,L
    public double [] WShort = {50,110,130.5};//S,M,L
    public double [] WJeans = {150.99,180,200};//S,M,L
    public double [] WDress = {350,400,450.99};//S,M,L
    public double [] WSkirts = {350.5,499.99,450.5};//S,M,L
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
WomenDep a = new WomenDep();
a.Recal();

}
}
```

Comment: 1. Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
2. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.